# Why does master craftsman allow skills like profession?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, skills

Why does the feat [master craftsman](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/master-craftsman---final) allow skills other than [craft](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/craft) (bows, weapons, armor)? Even if it was for the wondrous item aspect, it still does not make sense to me. Specifically to state that it allows [profession](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/profession) checks.

Even the crafting skill says

> A Craft skill is specifically focused on creating something.

Which is the purpose of crafting magical items. So why allow profession? Why not spell out the different crafting skills which are practical to the task at hand, like it does in the crafting skill?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there are some magic items that allow profession checks to create them.

[Scrolls](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Scrolls) allow for profession (Scribe), [Staves](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Staves) allow for profession (woodcutter), [Runes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Runes) allow for an applicable profession check, [Wands](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Wands) allow for profession (woodcutter), [Wondrous Items](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Wondrous-Items) allow for applicable profession checks.

I know that you can't use master craftsman to create spell activation/trigger items, I'm just listing all of the different items for completion sake.

Comment: Still feel that it should specifically state what should be used for what and help prevent shenanigans from taking place from its vague wording

Comment: Yeah, they're mostly using that so that they can add more things and still have the feat make sense without errata.  like they just added a new type of magic armor.  And listing out each individual rune/wondrous item's craft/profession would take a long time to backlog and more room in future books, so they leave it vague there as well.